# php pagination not displaying sql data

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to create a website which displays a picture and some information about the picture as a personal learning project.the issue i am having is not necessarily from the sql query but the pagination. i went through the code and realized it is caused by $page and $start but i don't know how to resolve it
the code is for pagination and sql query

```
<?php
include ('config/db_connect.php');

/* this is for the pages counter main */

// number of pages
$per_page =4;

//query pages
$pages_query = mysql_query("select count('track_id') from music_db");
$pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

$page = (isset ($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

$music_db_query = "select * from music_db limit $start , $per_page";

$music_db_execute = mysql_query($music_db_query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($music_db_execute)) {

echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/music.css">';
echo '<div style="background-color:#3a3a3a;">';
echo '<div class="medium-12 columns">';
echo '<article class="mainholder">';
echo '<div class="imageholder"><a href="#"><img src="'.$row['track_art'].'"/></a></div>';
echo '<div class="maindetails"><a href="#"><h5 style="color:white;">'.$row['track_title'].': '.$row['track_artist'].'</h5></a></div>';

$com = $row['track_comments']; 
$comred =readMoreFunction($com);  


echo '<div class="comments"><a style=" color:white;" href="#"><p>'.$comred .'</p></a></div>';
echo '</article>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
}

function readMoreFunction($story_desc,$link,$targetFile,$id) {  
//Number of characters to show  
$chars =210;  
$story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,$chars);  
$story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,strrpos($story_desc,' '));  
$story_desc = $story_desc." <a href='$link?$targetFile=$id'>Read More...</p>  </a>";  
return $story_desc;  
}


if($pages >= 1) {
    for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){

        echo '<a href ="$page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> ';
    }
}


mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: the data does not display but the pagination shows here is the link [link](http://http://learn4max.byethost10.com/index.php?page=music). pls check it out to see

Answer (score 0):

your code is proper just try to print the result. See what you are getting

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the pagination link you set:

```
<?php
    include ('config/db_connect.php');

    /* this is for the pages counter main */

    // number of pages
    $per_page =4;

    //query pages
    $pages_query = mysql_query("select count('track_id') from music_db");
    $pages = ceil(mysql_result($pages_query, 0) / $per_page);

    $page = (isset ($_GET['page'])) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
    $start = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

    $music_db_query = "select * from music_db limit $start , $per_page";

    $music_db_execute = mysql_query($music_db_query);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($music_db_execute)) {

    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/music.css">';
    echo '<div style="background-color:#3a3a3a;">';
    echo '<div class="medium-12 columns">';
    echo '<article class="mainholder">';
    echo '<div class="imageholder"><a href="#"><img src="'.$row['track_art'].'"/></a></div>';
    echo '<div class="maindetails"><a href="#"><h5 style="color:white;">'.$row['track_title'].': '.$row['track_artist'].'</h5></a></div>';

    $com = $row['track_comments']; 
    $comred =readMoreFunction($com);  


    echo '<div class="comments"><a style=" color:white;" href="#"><p>'.$comred .'</p></a></div>';
    echo '</article>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    }

    function readMoreFunction($story_desc,$link,$targetFile,$id) {  
    //Number of characters to show  
    $chars =210;  
    $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,$chars);  
    $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,strrpos($story_desc,' '));  
    $story_desc = $story_desc." <a href='$link?$targetFile=$id'>Read More...</p>  </a>";  
    return $story_desc;  
    }


    if($pages >= 1) {
        for($x=1; $x<=$pages; $x++){

            echo '<a href ="?page='.$x.'">'.$x.'</a> '; // Here I have updated file.. 
        }
    }


    mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: here is the link [link](http://http://learn4max.byethost10.com/index.php?page=music)

Comment: Can you enable error reporting and paste database sql in question?

Comment: its a free hosting and the option for handling errors is unavailable. but in xamp there are no errors till i click on the pagination here is the error:
Warning: include(pages/2.php): failed to open stream:                           No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\site1\index.php on line 97

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'pages/2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\site1\index.php on line 97

Comment: If you create separate page (not in your web app) and connect it with database then create a sample "music_db" table, you'll get the result. So there must be something wrong with your database connection (I assume) and without any error reporting, it is less possible to say anything.